# fscanf not scanning values properly

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 6
struct books{
    char name[100],author[100];
    int year,copies;
  };
struct books book1[SIZE],book2[SIZE],*list;

main()
{
  unsigned i;

  char line [ 100 ],temp1[100],temp2[100],c; /* line size */
  size_t len;

  FILE *file;

  file=fopen("input.txt","rw");

  int k=0;
  for(i=0;  fgets ( line, sizeof line, file) ; i++ ) /* read a line */
  {
    len = strlen(line);
    while (len && line[len-1] == '\n') line[--len] = 0;
    switch (i % 4) 
    {
      case 0: /* handle first line here */
             fscanf(file, "%[^\n]s",book1[k].author);
             break;
      case 1: /* handle second line here */

             fscanf(file, "%[^\n]s",book1[k].name);
             break;
      case 2: /* handle third line here */

             fscanf(file, "%[^\n]s",temp1);
             book1[k].year=atoi(temp1);
             break;
      case 3: /* handle fourth line here */

             fscanf(file, "%[^\n]s",temp2);
             book1[k].copies=atoi(temp2);
             break;
    }
    if(i % 4 == 3)
    {
      k++;
    }
  }
  fclose(file);

  i=0;
  while(i<SIZE)
  {
    printf("##########################################################################\n");
    printf("\nAuthor: %s\nBook: %s\nYear of Publication: %d\nNo of Copies: %d\n\n",book1[i].author,book1[i].name,book1[i].year,book1[i].copies);
    printf("##########################################################################\n");
    i++;
  }

}
```

**The input file is:**

```
A
Ruby On Rails
2004
100
J
Learn Python Easy Way
1967
100
D
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone
2012
150
D
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone
3045
140
Z
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone
2013
150
K
Inferno
1993
453
```

**But my output is:**

```
##########################################################################

Author: Ruby On Rails
Book: 2004
Year of Publication: 100
No of Copies: 0

##########################################################################
##########################################################################

Author: Learn Python Easy Way
Book: 1967
Year of Publication: 100
No of Copies: 0

##########################################################################
##########################################################################

Author: Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone
Book: 2012
Year of Publication: 150
No of Copies: 0

##########################################################################
##########################################################################

Author: Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone
Book: 3045
Year of Publication: 140
No of Copies: 0

##########################################################################
##########################################################################

Author: Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone
Book: 2013
Year of Publication: 150
No of Copies: 0

##########################################################################
##########################################################################

Author: Inferno
Book: 1993
Year of Publication: 453
No of Copies: 0

##########################################################################
```

Why is it skipping the first line? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: "fscanf not scanning values properly" - indeed. You'd be better off using `fgets()`, as I've already suggested that. Stay far away from `scanf()`, it's evil and unintuitive.

Comment: After calling `fgets()`, parse the line with `sscanf()`. Your `fscanf()` line scans the line after the line retrieved by `fgets()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had the similat issue. though it' not an answer but it will fix your problem.

Keep the first line of the input file empty and it will all work fine.Reason is mention by @anatolyg.

Answer (score 1):

```
fgets ( line, sizeof line, file)
```

This code skips the first line. Remove it and it will be good.

By the way, `fscanf` format string `"%[^\n]s"` is not good. Replace it by `"%[^\n]\n"` (or better, `"%[^\n]%*c"` - see comment by @chux) to read lines properly. Or replace `fscanf` by `fgets` to do the same without these funky format strings.

Comment: Note: `"%[^\n]\n"` is no different than `"%[^\n] "`.  By putting a `\n` or ` ` in the format string, any number of whitespace characters will be consumed, including any that begin the _next_ line.  Alternative formats include `"%[^\n]*%c"`.